# how to solve " can not read HTTP status line" in svn

Tags: eclipse, svn

When I use svn in myeclipse2013，it shosw me that

```
svn: can not read HTTP status line
svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/LNcrm/trunk/crm-ln-trunk'
```

how can I solve it?

Comment: can you connect from other computer? is the path correct?

Comment: It can work well on my cumputer in myeclipse6.5,but it show me taht error in myeclipse2013.

Answer (score 0):

What was the command line you intent to run (even through eclipse) ?
It seems the command line was badly formated.

Comment: But it worked well in my myEclipse6.5,when I use myeclipse2013,It breaked.I Just decompress the archive of svn and put it into the forder called dropins(E:\Users\zyy\AppData\Local\MyEclipse Professional\dropins).Does anything wrong? my english is alwful bad,hope you can understand.